# In Matlab: Generating random numbers from Alpha-stable pdf which expends in time (in a loop)

Tags: matlab, random

In Matlab, the following line of code generates 100000 random numbers from an Alpha-stable pdf (here Alpha=0.5):

```
 Rand = random('Stable',0.5,0,1,0,[1,100000]);
```

The distribution of Rand exactly matches the the 'theoretical' curve generated by

```
 PDF = makedist('Stable','alpha',0.5,'beta',0,'gam',1,'delta',0);
 x = -5:.1:5;
 PDF = pdf(PDF,x);
 figure
 plot(x,PDF,'r-.');
```

(to check, use, e.g.:)

```
 Data=Rand;
 Middle=0.01; 
 PosBinsUP=10.^(log10(Middle):0.05:log10(max(abs(Data))));
 PosBinsDown=10.^(log10(Middle):0.05:log10(abs(min(Data))));
 xbins=[-flip(PosBinsDown) -Middle:0.2:Middle PosBinsUP];
 [xpdf ypdf]= plotpdfc(Data, xbins);
 plot(xpdf(1:end-1),ypdf(1:end-1),'Or');
 xlim([-5,5]);
```

My question is:

How do I generate these Rands in a loop over 't', such that their distribution will expand in time, namely P(Rand) = t^(-1/Alpha) W(Rand/ t^(1/Alpha))?

Comment: you have to provide your t-axis, i.e. P(t) - how does these random variables generated over t, uniformly or there is a time-dependent distribution? if it is uniformly, you just generate the above samples from a discritized t with equal spacing and mix the results.

Comment: @FangQ     Thanks for you comment. My numbers are currently chosen from a stationary PDF, as seen in the example above. I wish to modify it so that I will get a time-dependent PDF (expending in a self-similar fashion, mimicking anomalous diffusion). I am not that I understand your answer though... Can you please explain more?

Comment: @Fang     P(Rand,t) is a function of Rand, at times, e.g., t=100:100:1000. For each time I want to generate a different P(Rand,t), and see that it is expanding like the scaling law I wrote.